# When is the content of a GET request received in python?

Tags: python, http, networking, python-requests

I am fairly new to computer networking and want to use the python `requests` library for downloading large files from an external FTP server. I have a conceptual question as to when the content of a large file is received and how the client tells the server when to send over the content.

My code looks somewhat like

```
import requests 

... 

response = requests.get(url_to_very_large_file, stream=True)

...

with open(save_path, "wb") as file: 
    for chunk in response.iter_chunks(chunk_size):
        file.write(chunk)
```

Now response arrives back from the server very quickly (less than a second), but the content of the file (say 2 GB heavy for the sake of argument) surely cannot arrive that fast. I'm also confused that response already has a `content` attribute. What happens under the hood?

More precisely:

1. What is in `response.content`?
2. Does the server now bombard my client with the 2 GB content right away, or is another request sent to the server when I ask for `response.iter_chunks` or `response.content.read()`?  At which point does the server start sending over the 2GB of content?
3. Does the server know in which chunk_size I am reading /expecting the files?
4. Where are the chunks stored in the meantime, if they are received by the client but not read into memory?

Comment: Just found a relevant section in the [requests documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow): "By default, when you make a request, the body of the response is downloaded immediately. You can override this behaviour and defer downloading the response body until you access the Response.content attribute with the stream parameter"

Answer (score 0):

1. `response.content` attribute contains the returned bytes from the remote server. This attribute is a [*property*](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property), so if you sent the request with `stream=True` option, it won't contain the content upon creation, until you access it- which is the moment where it'll pull all the data from the server.
2. When you send a request to a server, you're establishing a connection which the server will send data through. This doesn't have to happen at once, and if your underlying client is not pulling a data to its RAM, server will wait for you for a while. By using `.iter_chunks` method you're slowly pulling data from the server few bytes at a time.
3. They don't, and considering how TCP connection works it isn't necessary either.
4. Server doesn't send us a data until we got a room for it, hence they're not on our machine unless they're on our memory.

If you have already learnt other languages like Java, you could think of property as getter/setter but in more integrated way. Check the post I linked above for better explanations.

It might be helpful to learn how TCP connection and socket works, since those are the ones that does all the stuff under the hood.